# Change the font style of one item in a wx python ListCtrl

Tags: python, fonts, wxwidgets, listctrl

I am having issues changing the font of a single item in an wx list ctrl.  I have 1 row and 3 columns in my ListCtrl. The code below should change the font of the item located at row = 0 col = 0 to bold. But instead it changes the font style of ALL the items in row 0 to bold. In summary, I only want the first item in the first row to be bold and not the entire row itself.

Is it even possible to change one items font without changing the entire row?

Thankyou

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)   

        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1        

        item = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(0,0)
        print "itemText", item.GetText()       
        # Get its font, change it, and put it back:
        font = item.GetFont()
        font.SetWeight(wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
        item.SetFont(font)
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(item)  

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

with wx.ListCtrl, you can't have control at the sub item level.
If you change font, it will change for entire row.

Therefore this is not possible.

Heres the ticket number:
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/3030